# Generate unique string in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE #Agency 
 (
  AgencyID int PRimary KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  AgencyName varchar(100), 
  AgencyCode varchar(50)
  )
```

I want to generate a unique agency code while inserting into the table...Agency code should consists of only Alphabets ..no numbers or special characters

Thank you

Comment: Is it necessary to avoid numbers or special characters? If that was acceptable, you could use the NEWID() function to generate a GUID for you. Details here: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/generate_new_guid_uniqueidentifier_in_sql_server.aspx

Comment: That sounds like you are generating a natural key in the database. Could turn into a tin of worms later on that.

Comment: yes ..i know that GUID option..but it is compulsary to take only alphabets..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something as simple as casting your ID to varchar and replacing every digit with letter (or combination).

1=A, 2=B, etc..

So, as long your IDs are unique, so will the code be.

Snippet could be something like:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    CAST(AgencyID AS VARCHAR(50))
    ,'1','A'),'2','B'),'3','C'),'4','D'),'5','E'),'6','F'),'7','G'),'8','H'),'9','I'),'0','J')
```

If you want to do it during insert, you can use IDENT_CURRENT('tablename') to get the value that inserts for identity column.

```
      INSERT INTO Agency (AgencyName, AgencyCode)
    SELECT 'Name001', 
              REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
              CAST(IDENT_CURRENT('Agency') AS VARCHAR(50))
              ,'1','A'),'2','B'),'3','C'),'4','D'),'5','E'),'6','F'),'7','G'),'8','H'),'9','I'),'0','J')

;
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9002f/1)**

Creating a function that converts your number to string and/or computed column might be prettier for use.

**[DEMO using function and computed columns](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d2bf/2)**

EDIT:

**[DEMO with updated request to make at least 5 string long character](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a177b/2)**

Comment: My answer is kind of an alternative view on the question, but you're answering directly, so +1.

Comment: thanks  for the answer..but the code should have atleast 5 characters

Comment: @SQL006 You can add additional logic to function creating code before Return. Maybe if it's shorter than 5 characters to add few X letters in front. Check new demo in edited post.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you generate the string in the application. That way you can use a language that is better suitable for procedural code than T-SQL is. It is best-practice anyway to keep logic out of SQL Server if possible.